# c++ txt file into array line by line string and int for card game

Tags: c++, arrays, file, readline

I need to read a `.txt` file into an **array** and store them in a **deck** so to speak. The `.txt` file looks like this:

```
1 Dwarf 2 4
11 Armour 1
6 Wall 0 5
10 Sword 2
4 Bless 2 2
1 Cannon 4 1
1 Dwarf 2 4
1 Cannon 4 1
2 Fireball 3
1 Cannon 4 1
```

Each line is: `type` `name` `attack` and `health`.

I am only allowed to use type 1 cards; i.e. I need a deck for each type.

I have looked but I am struggling to find an answer for this specific problem. Can anyone point me in the right direction using plain English?

Comment: Arguably, your best bet at this point are these [C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: 1) Define a card-representing structure; 2) Define a function that reads and returns one such card; 3) Use the function repeatedly.

Comment: If you do some google search, you can absolutely find plenty number of examples.

Comment: I have googled but i am struggling to understand how to implement as i have 2 files to do this with in the same program.

Comment: Search the internet for "c++ read file struct space separated".  There are already a plethora of similar questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: What is a *type 1* card and how does it differ from a *type 2* card?

Comment: type 2 is just a different type of minion

Comment: There are some problems with your English. In particular, I don't understand the meaning of this sentence: "I am only allowed to use type 1 cards so also need to figure this out."

Comment: i mean there re multiple types of card i.e type 1, type 2 etc. however i am only allowed to use type 1 cards so need to filter these so they are the only ones iin the deck

Comment: " i am only allowed to use type 1 cards so need to filter these" @MatthewAlanGibson-Storey ok, then How can you recognize the card type? Do you already know how to filter (irrelevant detail) or is that part of your question (too broad) ?

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume your records look like this:

```
1 Dwarf 2 4
```

To *model* this in a class:

```
class Type_1_Card
{
    int         type;
    std::string name;
    int         attack;
    int         health;
};
```

In *modeling*, you choose a type and member that best fits the column of data.
Each row will be an instance of the model.

Speaking of rows, you'll need some kind of *container* for each row (otherwise known as a *database*).  Since the number of rows *is unknown at run-time*, use a `std::vector`, because it can expand as necessary.

```
std::vector<Type_1_Card> database;
```

To honor the principles of *data hiding* and *encapsulation*, we'll have the class input the data, since the class knows the layout (fields and members).  C++ allows overloading of operators and methods, so we'll overload a familiar method:  `operator>>`.

```
class Type_1_Card
{
     // yada, yada, yada
  public:  
     friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Type_1_Card& card);
};

std::istream&
Type_1_Card ::
operator>>(std::istream& input, Type_1_Card& card)
{
    input >> card.type;
    input >> card.name;
    input >> card.attack;
    input >> card.health;
    return input;
}
```

This hides the data by allowing the following code to read in the cards:

```
std::fstream data_file(/*...*/);
Type_1_Card card;
while (data_file >> card)
{
    database.push_back(card);
}
```

Magically, the contents of the `card` are not exposed, hidden, and the functionality is *encapsulated* into the class or object.

**Edit 1: Expanding the encapsulation**
In your program, you may want to find a card by name.  You can add a method to the class, then search the database:

```
class Type_1_Card
{
    // yada, yada, yada
  public:
    bool is_card_name(const std::string& key_name) const
    {
        // Remember, comparison is case sensitive, 'A' != 'a'
        return name == key_name;
    }
};
```

This allows you to search the database for a card using a name.
Here's the brute force technique.  There are simpler methods that use library functions, but that is left for further research.

```
const size_t index = 0U;
const size_t size = database.size();
for (index = 0; index < size; ++index)
{
    if (database[index].is_card_name("Dwarf"))
    {
        std::cout << "Dwarf card found at index " << index << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: that looks complex for what i am trying to do. i have created the struct however when trying to read it in i just get identifier name is not defined

Comment: This is not complex.  How are you reading in your class members?

Comment: Search the internet for "c++ loose coupling" and "c++ tight coupling".  Tight coupling leads to many nasty errors down the road, when making changes to existing code.  This can be seen in industry code.

Comment: It is not complex; spend time to understand it. Cutting corners will cause you much pain later on.

Comment: ive sort of got my code working, should i start a new question or just edit the question?

Comment: If your code is working and want review, post to [codereview.se].

Comment: If you like debugging through StackOverflow, then post another question.  You may want to check any answers that were helpful before creating a new question.